# Place Admob between a Frame Layout and Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, admob

Hi I am trying to place admob banner in between two layouts. But the admob is overlaying the Relative Layout Content. I got a warning from Admob team regarding this issue. Kindly help me to resolve it.

Code is as Follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_frag"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->
    <com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srl_direction="both">    


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                  
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"/>

    </com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>

    <com.exfileexplorer.filemanager.ui.views.FastScroller
        android:id="@+id/fastscroll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nofilelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_drive_file_white_36dp"/>

        <TextView
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:id="@+id/nofiletext"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/nofiles"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Check the screenshot to get an idea.
[image]

How to avoid overlapping? Please help me..

Comment: Remove framelayout , because in framelayout it works like stack.

Comment: so what layout should I use?

Comment: Relative or linear depends on you which fits you best.

Comment: In Linear there is no chance of overlapping, it place views in either horizontal or vertical direction.